# Youtube api sample code Can't run

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am playing with google api. This code is from codeacademy.

Here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="response"></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is javascript:

```
    // Your use of the YouTube API must comply with the Terms of Service:
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

    // Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
    function showResponse(response) {
        var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
    }

    // Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
    function onClientLoad() {    
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
    }

    // Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
    function onYouTubeApiLoad() {

        console.log("onYouTubeApiLoad");
        // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
        gapi.client.setApiKey('1111111111AIzaSyBenRS7G9WPDylh2JAXOeD2uLsao6VW2QY');

        search();
    }

    function search() {
        // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: 'snippet',
            q: 'surfboards'
        });

        // Send the request to the API server,
        // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
        request.execute(onSearchResponse);
    }

    // Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
    function onSearchResponse(response) {
        showResponse(response);
    }
```

It's suppose to work fine. But I don't know why - function onYouTubeApiLoad() - is never called. What is wrong? Can't figure out.

Comment: Seems to work fine at http://plnkr.co/edit/z9AX5iKwYdTfuM7GpzO8?p=preview Is your file really named app.js and is it in the same folder as the html file ?

Comment: Hello! yes it's stored as app.js in the same directory. If I put console.log("onClientLoad") inside onClientLoad() - there is the right output in the console. But after that - nothing

Comment: and of course in here I put fake api key.But on my local machine I use actual api key

Comment: I am stupid. I need to put it somewhere and work with http or https. But I was trying to work on file://

Comment: What is the error that appears in the logs when using the actual API key?

Comment: @Teyam I have solved the problem. You mean in the console? Actualy nothing in there =/ I don't know how debug/ spot errors in react

Comment: That's great! Can you please share what you have done to solve the issue? Others might also be encountering the same problem.